# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(p+\frac1n\right)^n$ exist for any p greater than 1?

Tags: limits

And, more importantly, can anyone point me to a proof either way? My barely remembered high-school math is sufficient to demonstrate that for $p=2$ the expression explodes, but not enough to say whether there is some value of $p$ near 1 for which the expression still converges. Invoking the basic principle that I would have heard of it if such a value existed has not sufficiently resolved the question for me.

Comment: $\left(p+\frac1n\right)^n > p^n$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean "does (this limit) exist for any $p>1$?" As written, the title is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, I overlook a missing word. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

Note that for any constant $p > 1$
$$ \left( p + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n > p^n > 1$$
and thus
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( p + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} p^n = \infty$$
and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e \approx 2.71828... > 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at this is

$$
\left( p + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \left( p \left(1+ \frac{1/p}{n}\right)\right)^n= \left( p \right)^n \left(1+ \frac{1/p}{n}\right)^n.
$$

The second term goes to $e^{1/p}$ as $n \to \infty$ so overall, this limit tends to

$$
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} p^n\right) e^{1/p}
$$

which is going to be infinite for *any* $p > 1$. For $p = 1$, the limit is $e$, for $|p| < 1$ the limit is $0$, and for $p \leq -1$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: That shows nicely how quickly it will diverge! Very nice.